# Remove rows which are matched by multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I got two data frames. One contains the main data (called `dtt_main`) and could be huge, the other one (called `dtt_selected`) contains only two columns, which are also available in the main data frame. For every entry in the `dtt_selected`, I want to check whether the same values are included in `dtt_main`. If so, this row(s) should be removed (these values are not unique in the `dtt_main`, so one could remove multiple rows by applying this criterion). I managed to write a small function which does exactly this, but is really slow because I have to iterate over both dataframes simultaneously. I would be very happy about a faster, more pandas-like solution. Thanks!

```py
# The real data set contains ~100_000 rows and ~1000 columns
dtt_main = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,1,1,2,2,4,5,4], 
    'b': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,6], 
    'data': list('abcdefgh')
})

dtt_selected = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,1,2,4], 
    'b': [1,5,3,6]
})

def remove_selected(dtt_main, dtt_selected):
    for row_select in dtt_select.itertuples():
        for row_main in dtt_main.itertuples():
            # First entry of the tuples is the index!
            if (row_select[1] == row_main[1]) & (row_select[2] == row_main[2]):
                dtt_main.drop(row_main[0], axis='rows', inplace=True)

remove_selected(dtt_main, dtt_selected)
print(dtt_main)
>>> a  b data
>>> 2  1  2    c
>>> 3  2  2    d
>>> 5  4  3    f
>>> 6  5  4    g
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) See the section on `LEFT-Excluding JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could left join the `DataFrames` using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). By setting `indicator=True`, it adds a column `_merge` which will have `'both'` if it occurs also in `dtt_selected` (and therefore should be dropped) and `'left_only'` if it was only in `dtt_main` (and thus should be kept). Now in hte next line, you can first keep only the columns that have `'left_only'`, and then drop the now unnecessary `'_merge'`-column:

```
df1 = dtt_main.merge(dtt_selected, how='left', indicator=True)
df1[df1['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns='_merge')
#Output
#   a  b data
#2  1  2    c
#3  2  2    d
#5  4  3    f
#6  5  4    g
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! There is a small mistake in the second line, it should be changed to `df1[df1['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop('_merge', axis='columns')`